# How to iterate through each list in a list in C#?

Tags: c#, list, ienumerable

I have two lists. I am adding one list to another list. Then how can i iterate through each list that contain all the list?

```
List<int> FS = new List<int>();
List<int> F = new List<int>();
```

I am adding one list to another list

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbCloudFederation"].ToString()))
{
     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Id FROM tbl_Provider_Registrations", con);
     con.Open();
     SqlDataReader Reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
     while (Reader.Read())
     {
        F.Add(Convert.ToInt32(Reader["Id"]));
        // I want to modify F list later
        FS.AddRange(F);
     }
}
```

Is it possible to iterate through all the list that contain in Fs?

Comment: Each time you `FS.AddRange(F);`, it will add *all* the contents of `F` at  that point, not just the most recent addition.

Comment: @crashmstr You mean that each element in List F will add to List Fs individually. Not as a list?

Comment: @crashmstr Ya.. I got. So is there any way to add a list to another list

Comment: With that inside the loop, `F` gets more elements each iteration, then *all* of those elements in `F` for that iteration get added to `FS`, so `FS` will have many duplicates.

Comment: what is the point of `F` in the first place? Why not just add the values straight to `FS`?

Comment: What do you mean "add a list to another list"? Add the contents of one list to a different list? If that is the intent, then move the `FS.AddRange` outside the loop, then you add all elements of `F` to the `FS` list.

Comment: but in case you really want a list of lists then change `... FS = new List<List<int>>();` and `while ...  { F = new List<int>(); ... FS.Add(F); }`

Comment: List<int32> FS= new List<Int32>(F); if you can move the coping out of the loop. Otherwise with the way you are doing I am sure you will end up with lot of duplicates!

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are trying to achieve.  At the end of your `while` loop, FS will simply be a list of integers, with significant repetition.  For example, if your reader produced the sequence {1, 3, 8, 2}, then FS would contain {1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 8, 1, 3, 8, 2}.  Perhaps you mean for FS to be a list of lists, ie, { {1}, {1, 3}, {1, 3, 8}, {1, 3, 8, 2} }?

Comment: @object88 Ys. you got what i need. How can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make FS a `List<List<int>>`, and call `FS.Add(F)` at the end of your while loop.  Although I'm not sure this will get you where you want to go, as you are not instantiating F inside the loop.